# Cant return a value using a method

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that returns the length of a variable to a method so it can print it out. However, this prints nothing. I want it to print the length of "abc".

```
public class parameters {

public static void main (String[]args) {


}
public static void Jumble (int lettersABC) {

    System.out.println(lettersABC);
}

public static int letters () {
    String alpha = "abc";
int jay = alpha.length();
return jay;
}




}
```

Comment: I dont see any functon calls.

Comment: Your main program is empty...

Comment: Your program does exactly what you have programmed it to do. Nothing.

Comment: Please follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). Class names should always start with a capital letter. Functions starts with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called any method. Try calling it in main method.

Do you mean something like this ?

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    System.out.println(letters());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't call `letters ()` from `main`, that's why nothing is printing.

You are looking for this:

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    Jumble (letters ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is empty. It doesn't contain any call to constructor or method to print length of string.

I think, your program would be like this.

```
       public class parameters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jumble(letters());

    }

    public static void Jumble(int lettersABC) {

        System.out.println(lettersABC);
    }

    public static int letters() {
        String alpha = "abc";
        int jay = alpha.length();
        return jay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why do you need Jumble method.

Cleaner code:

```
public class parameters{

    public static void main (String[]args) {
       String testIn = "abc";
       System.out.println(letters(testIn));
    }

    public static int letters (String in) {
       return in.length();
    }
}
```